# nginx doesn't pass outer request to localhost

Tags: nginx, proxy, java, http-status-code-404, jetty

Jetty server runs on localhost:8080 and **successfully** responses when I make requests via curl (putty):

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"message":"Hi"}' http://localhost:8080
```

I have following **nginx.conf** configuration:

```
server{
        listen 80;
        server_name 52.27.79.132;
        root /data/www;
        index index.html

        # static files: .png, .css, .js...
        location /static/ {
           root /data/www;
        }

        location ^~/api/*{
            proxy_pass        http://localhost:8080;
            proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header  Host $http_host;
        }

    }

# include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
```

Java servlet runs, when jetty server gets request to "/"

Browser successfully returns index.html page, but when javascript makes AJAX-request to 'http://52.27.79.132/api/' I get 404 error

Does anyone know why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex is not right in your version. However, you don't actually need regex matching in your case, so you can use this version:

```
location /api {
    proxy_pass        http://localhost:8080;
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header  Host $http_host;
}
```

If you want to use regex for some reason, the first line should look like this:

```
location ^~ ^/api/.*
```

The dot means any character and asterisk means repeat 0 or more times.

In your original location line, you repeated `/` 0 or more times.

Comment: Many thanks! 
finally I changed location to this one: ' location ^~ /api/ '

Comment: Actually you need to use `location ^~ ^/api/`. The location you used will match any URI that contains `/api/` anywhere on it, like `/some/path/api/resource`. The `^` means start of line in regex, which eliminates the problem.